# Split large CSV to Multiple CSV containing each row

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am using Pandas to split large csv to multiple csv each containing single row.
I have a csv having 1 million records and using below code it is taking to much time.
For Eg: In the above case there will be 1 million csv created.
Anyone can help me how to decrease time in splitting csv.

```
for index, row in lead_data.iterrows():
    row.to_csv(row['lead_id']+".csv")
```

lead_data is the dataframe object.

Thanks

Comment: Why on earth do you want to create 1 million of CSV files? Large part of the slowdown will also come from the filesystem. Most of filesystems are not tailored for so many files in one directory. You seem to have picked wrong approach to solve your problem...

Comment: I want large file to store in aws s3 bucket and splitting file will help me to check whether any lead_id present in that object or not by giving the file name as lead_id.
So in this way file system will also behave like db structure where i can put sql queries using s3select.
Can u suggest me any better approach.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to loop through the data. Filter records by lead_id and the export the data to CSV file. That way you will be able to split the files based on the lead ID (assuming).
Example, split all EPL games where arsenal was at home:

```
data=pd.read_csv('footbal/epl-2017-GMTStandardTime.csv')
print("Selecting Arsenal")
ft=data.loc[data['HomeTeam']=='Arsenal']
print(ft.head())
# Export data to CSV
ft.to_csv('arsenal.csv')
print("Done!")
```

This way it is much faster than using one record at a time.

Comment: But in my csv lead_id is the primary key so there  are 1 million unique lead_id.
Above code will also take same time.

Comment: Given lead_id is the primary key, does each file has records about the same lead_id?

Comment: Each file will contain only single lead_id and which will be unique from all other files.
So count of files will be count of rows in large file.